# Can the wolves catch the hare?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics, combinatorial-game-theory

Say you have 7 positions. 1 Hare and two Wolves in the following starting positions:

H

o     o

W   W

  o   o

The hare can take a step of size 2.

The Wolves can take a step of size 1.

The game starts by making a step with one of the wolves.

The hare and one of the wolves move subsequently.

The game is over when the Hare steps on a wolf.

Can the wolves win this? If so, how?

Comment: I'm not quite sure about the rules: is the diagram supposed to be a circle, so every position has exactly two neighbours? If not, which positions are adjacent, and what constitutes 'a step of size 1/2'? What happens if a wolf steps on a hare? Is the game over as well? If so, I don't see how the hare can win, if one of the wolves moves 1 'down' (in your picture). Either it has to step on a wolf, or is caught by the other wolf in the next round.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. It is indeed supposed to be a circle, so every position has exactly two neighbors. If a wolf steps on a hare the game is not over. The wolves can also both be on the same position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wolves cannot win. Suppose they could. Take a winning sequence of moves such that the hare played in a way that maximized the length of the game. Eventually such a sequences leads to it being some rotation of the starting position with it being the hare's move. Backing up two moves, it is the hare's move in one of the following situations (two are pictured, the other two are similar by symmetry):

```
  o          o
W   o      o   o
H   W   or H   W
 o o        W o
```

However, now we see that the hare can go to the lower right spot instead of the top spot, extending the game further. This contradicts that the hare played optimally, so the wolves cannot win.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! Is this also the case if the wolves would be in the same position at some point in the game?